# Italicize word to the left, but set continued typing not in italics

Tags: vba, ms-word, italics

I've been working with ChatGPT to italicizes word to the left of cursor, but it sets continued typing not in italics in [Word 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Word#Word_2019). But after an hour, all we've been able to do is the following:

```
Sub ItalicizeWordToLeft()
    On Error Resume Next ' Ignore errors temporarily

    Dim autoFormatStatus As Boolean
    Dim currentCursorPosition As Integer

    ' Store the current auto-format setting
    autoFormatStatus = Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceHyperlinks

    ' Temporarily disable auto-formatting changes
    Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceHyperlinks = False

    ' Store the current cursor position
    currentCursorPosition = Selection.Start

    ' Italicize the word to the left of the cursor
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.Font.Italic = True

    ' Move the cursor to the end of the italicized word
    Selection.EndOf Unit:=wdWord, Extend:=wdMove

    ' Enable auto-formatting changes back to the original status
    Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceHyperlinks = autoFormatStatus

    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling to default
End Sub
```

This italics the word to the left, leaves the cursor at the end of the word but continued typing is in italics.  How do I modify so continued typing is not in italics?

Comment: Chat GPT knows a fair amount of vb but not vba. It confuses the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ChatGPT makes it more complicated than it should be.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ItalicizeWordToLeft()
    Selection.Collapse Word.wdCollapseStart
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
    Selection.Expand Unit:=wdWord
    If Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = " " Then
        Selection.End = Selection.End - 1
    End If
    Selection.Font.Italic = True
    Selection.Collapse Word.wdCollapseEnd
    Selection.Font.Italic = False
    ' Selection.TypeText " Just for testing"
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Selection.Collapse method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.collapse?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158662757)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Selection.Expand method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.expand?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158662785)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, but your method doesn't work

Comment: Pleases clarify the meaning of `doesn't work`. Didn't set `Italic`? The code is tested on Word 365.

Comment: it doesn't work in word 2019.  Nothing seems to happen.  wait, I tried it again.  It works if you are not at the end of the document but if it's the last word it doesn't work

Comment: Do you mind to run the code with debugging? Let's see which line doesn't work.

Comment: not sure how to do that, looking it up

Comment: I have updated the code. Please try it again.

Comment: now it doesn't work at all

Comment: Is my screenshot what you are looking for?

Comment: what screen shot? I removed chatgpt makes it more complicated as I didn't see anything.  as the type was so small.  But anyway your current version does not work

Comment: I don't get it. What's `the type was so small`.

Comment: ahh, no that's not what I'm looking for.  Lets say i 'type' is the last word in the document. I want a shortcut to italicsize it and allow more typing in regular (no italics) mode.  No reason for you to insert text

Comment: Please remove `Selection.TypeText " Just for testing"`. The line is just for testing purpose.

Comment: sorry about all that.  just tried it again and it works.  Must of done something screwing

Answer (score 0):

Working for over an hour with ChatGPT, we finally have it working with the following:

```
Sub ItalicizeWordToLeftAndAddX()
    On Error Resume Next ' Ignore errors temporarily

    ' Store the current auto-format setting
    Dim autoFormatStatus As Boolean
    autoFormatStatus = Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceHyperlinks

    ' Temporarily disable auto-formatting changes
    Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceHyperlinks = False

    ' Italicize the word to the left of the cursor
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.Font.Italic = True

    ' Move to the end of the italicized word
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1

    ' Add a space and an "X" at the end
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" X"

    ' Turn Italics to false for the added "X"
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.Font.Italic = False

    ' Move back to the end of the italicized word
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1

    ' Delete the added "X"
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter

    ' Move the cursor back to regular text
    Selection.Font.Italic = False

    ' Enable auto-formatting changes back to the original status
    Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceHyperlinks = autoFormatStatus

    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling to default
End Sub
```

Could someone let me know if there is an better way to do this?

Comment: Why is there a question in an answer? [Stack Overflow is ***not*** a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828)